# How to dynamically calculate value of a column in edit mode in Vaadin 8 grid component

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

I have a table in my UI which is a grid component. The value of one of the columns is calculated based on other column input values. So for example there are columns A,B, and C and value of column C = A + B. What I want to achieve is when user edits a row, **before clicking the save button** it would be able to see the calculated value in edit mode.
Is there a possibility to do that without Javascript or if not, how can I run a javascript snippet on onBlur event of the editable columns (A and B).
The calculated column is not editable by user.

This is a non functional code snippet that shows more or less what is the basis of my code.

```java
Grid<Numbers> grid = new Grid<>(Numbers.class, false);
Editor<Numbers> editor = grid.getEditor();

Grid.Column<Numbers> aColumn = grid
        .addColumn(Numbers::getA).setHeader("A")
        .setWidth("120px").setFlexGrow(0);
Grid.Column<Numbers> bColumn = grid.addColumn(Numbers::getB)
        .setHeader("B").setWidth("120px").setFlexGrow(0);
Grid.Column<Numbers> cColumn = grid.addColumn(Numbers::getC)
        .setHeader("C");
Grid.Column<Numbers> editColumn = grid.addComponentColumn(numbers -> {
    Button editButton = new Button("Edit");
    editButton.addClickListener(e -> {
        if (editor.isOpen())
            editor.cancel();
        grid.getEditor().editItem(numbers);
    });
    return editButton;
}).setWidth("150px").setFlexGrow(0);

Binder<Numbers> binder = new Binder<>(Numbers.class);
editor.setBinder(binder);
editor.setBuffered(true);

TextField aField = new TextField();
aField.setWidthFull();
binder.forField(aField)
        .bind(Numbers::getA, Numbers::setA);
aColumn.setEditorComponent(aField);

TextField bField = new TextField();
bField.setWidthFull();
binder.forField(bField)
        .bind(Numbers::getB, Numbers::setB);
bColumn.setEditorComponent(bField);

TextField cField = new TextField();
cField.setWidthFull();
binder.forField(cField)
        .bind(Numbers::getC, Numbers::setC);
cColumn.setEditable(false);

Button saveButton = new Button("Save", e -> editor.save());
Button cancelButton = new Button(VaadinIcon.CLOSE.create(),
        e -> editor.cancel());
cancelButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_ICON,
        ButtonVariant.LUMO_ERROR);
HorizontalLayout actions = new HorizontalLayout(saveButton,
        cancelButton);
actions.setPadding(false);
editColumn.setEditorComponent(actions);
```

I tried adding this to some events:

```java
Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("alert('the calculated value')");
```

The problem is the elements that are created by grid component have no id, so accessing them directly is not an option. Traversing dom is not really feasible too.

Comment: Have you tried adding a value change listener to the input? Anyway
please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)/
the code you have tried.

Comment: @cfrick I didn't really try anything. I tried to use execute script but there is no id in generated dom elements so it was not useful.

Comment: I don't know if there are any special rules for the inline grid form, but I'd try to add a value change listener to the binder (or to the two input fields) and calculate the other value into the form field. Value changes are triggered in text fields basically on-blur; you can even make them "more eager" than that.

Comment: Thanks, this value change listener seems promising. I try it to see if it can solve the problem. And onblur is eager enough for me :)